# Ruby has_many associated models query with Postgres database (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have model, Physician, that has_many Patients.  Trying write a query that only results in Physicians that have all cured patients.  So each Patient for a Physician must have the attribute "is_cured: true"  (or at least is not nil for all the Physicians patients).

Have this so far, but Physicians are showing up when just having one cured patient, not all:

`@physicians = Physician.includes(:patients)
                        .where.not(patients: { id: nil })
                        .where(patients: { is_cured: true })`

Models:

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :patients
  has_many :recommendations, through: :patients
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :recommendation
end

class Recommendation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :patients
  has_many :physicians, through: :patients
end
```

Thanks for any assistance you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Fetches physicians who have at-least one uncured patient
phys_with_uncured_patients = Physician.joins(:patients).where(patients: { is_cured: false })

#Fetches physicians who have at-least one patient and all are cured.
Physician.joins(:patients).where.not(id: phys_with_uncured_patients)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
physician_ids = Patient.where(is_cured: false).pluck(:physician_id)

Physician.joins(:patients).where.not(id: physician_ids)
```

Comment: The question also expects to filter out physicians who have zero patients, your second query doesn't filter them.